# Ajax cannot get success or error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to show search results via AJAX to the view.  The action gets JSON and sends it, but the AJAX seems to not be receiving the data.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#btnSearchForUser").click(function () {
        var searchUserResult = $("#UserName").val();

        var jsonResult = {
            UserName: searchUserResult
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Car/ReturnCars",
            data: jsonResult,
            success: function (jsonResults) {
                var table = $("#tblCarResults");
                table.empty();

                for (var i = 0; i < jsonResults.length; i++) {
                    var btnBill = "<td><input type='button' value='Get bill'/> <td>";
                    var btnReturn = "<td><input type='button' value='Return car'/></td>";
                    var tdUserName = "<td>" + jsonResults[i].UserName + "</td>";
                    var tdManufacture = "<td>" + jsonResults[i].Manufacturer + "</td>";
                    var tdModel = "<td>" + jsonResults[i].Model + "</td>";
                    var tdFee = "<td>" + jsonResults[i].Fee + "</td>";

                    var tr = tdManufacture + tdModel + tdFee + btnBill + btnReturn;
                    $(tr).appendTo(table);
                };
            },

            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.status);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

**Edit:** the `success` was not a mistype and has been corrected.

Comment: spelling mistake "success" not "succsess".

Comment: No Matt :D I was wrong :D Well it must be comment, anyway — its too short.

Comment: However, the problem still stands.

Comment: Is the server sending JSON with the appropriate headers?

Comment: What is `btnSearchForUser`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not answered my question in the comments. I am guessing btnSearchForUser is a submit button and you are not cancelling its click action.

```
$("#btnSearchForUser").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```